# Find all complex $z$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nz^2}}{n}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Find all complex $z$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nz^2}}{n}$ is convergent.

I use a root test:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\frac{e^{nz^2}}{n}|^{1/n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\frac{e^{nz^2}}{n}|^{1/n}=|e^{z^2}|$

And now I have to find all $z$ such that $|e^{z^2}|<1$.

Is that correct and how can I do that?

Comment: Do you remember what $\lvert e^w\rvert$ is for $w\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Try writing $z = x+iy$ and expanding $|e^{(x+iy)^2}|$.

Comment: But is all I did before correct?

Comment: Daniel, I don't know with that modulus

Comment: What you did so far is correct to find the $z$ for which the series converges absolutely. But the series also converges (conditionally) for some $z$ such that $\lvert e^{z^2}\rvert = 1$. To find the modulus of $e^w$, it is useful to know that $\overline{e^w} = e^{\overline{w}}$. Then you can compute $\lvert e^w\rvert^2 =\;?$

Comment: Also note that $|e^{iy}|=1$

Comment: But it is $|e^{(z^2)}|$, not $|(e^z)^2)|$

Comment: @luka5z If you generally know what $\lvert e^w\rvert$ is, then plug in $w = z^2$.

Comment: $|e^{a^2+2iab-b^2}|=|e^{a^2-b^2}(\cos(2ab)+i\sin(2ab))|$ yes?

Comment: Right, now what can you say about $|e^{i2ab}|$?  Or $|e^{it}|$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ for that matter...

Comment: they are equal to 1

Comment: so it turnes out that $e^{a^2-b^2}$ should be less than $1$ so $a^2<b^2$ yes?